# How do you get the Model & Serial Number of a USB drive on Mac?

Tags: terminal, usb

How do I find the Model Name & serial number of a flash drive on OS X 10.11?

I remember learning it in class, and I believe you would go in the terminal but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 2):

I spotlighted "System Information" which comes up with a console for all hardware on your system, and there is a tab for USB.

Comment: Do you have screen shots to highlight your approach?